# Pass variable from Javascript file to Express/Node file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Basic File Structure:

```
public
    javascript
        script.js
app.js
    views
        startprofile.ejs
```

I'm using the `startprofile.ejs` which also uses the `script.js`, I have an array of objects in the `script.js` and need to pass it to my `app.js` to edit information on a User model.

Not sure how to approach this.

Code in `script.js`, currently logs strings in console that I need to pass to `app.js`:

```
var lis = document.getElementsByClassName("notSkill");

for (i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    lis[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        if(this.className == "skill") {
            this.className = "notSkill";
        } else {
            this.className = "skill";
        }
    });
}

var save = document.getElementById("save");
save.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var skills = document.getElementsByClassName("skill");
    for(i = 0; i < skills.length; i++) {
        console.log(skills[i].textContent)
    }
})
```

Comment: jquery, `$.post`, `app.post` ... and so on... watch tutorials in Youtube.

Comment: Did you try an `Event`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+post+expressjs&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=WUFYWNPIK7Hi8AeR17IQ#q=jquery+post+expressjs&tbm=vid